# Is there a way to apply a filter to a part of an Excel file?

Tags: excel

I have 2 columns I want to filter.
The column A contains constructor name and column B modele name of an equipment.

I want first to order by constructor name.
Then order for each constructor by equipment name.

Something like this :

[image: result expected]

Is there a way to to do this in Excel ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they need to remain with the same corresponding data then just filter both columns by highlighting them then filtering.  Sort by the second column, then sort by the first column.

Comment: What do you mean when you say ```by highlighting them``` ?

Comment: I mean by selecting those two columns.

Comment: Can you explain how you do that ? Because when I try what you say, it doesn't sort the first column correctly.

Comment: Select both columns( by cicking on the column letter and dragging to select the columns you want to filter). Go to Data on your ribbon - select filter. Then filter your second column however you want then the first column.